# Node.js: Handle 2 requests to HTTP server one after another

Tags: node.js, http

Upon POST to http server, the server has to:

1. send TCP message to external agent
2. receive TCP reply from external agent
3. send response to client

But my client sends 2 POSTs almost on the same time.
How can I make sure that the 2 POST requests will be handled one after another ?

```js
function sendReq (body, res)
{
    var byteArr=[];
    len = body.length;
    //get pure data without {,}
    data = body.substr (1,len-2);
    //convert to array
    arr = data.split (',');

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        num = parseInt (arr[i]);
        var numArr = num2arr (num);
        byteArr = byteArr.concat (numArr);
    }

    res.writeHead (200,{
    'Content-Type':'text/plain',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'});


if (arr[1]==28)
{
    var body = Buffer.alloc (392);
    res.write (body);
}

if (arr[1]==11)
{
    var body = Buffer.alloc (28);
    res.write (body);
}

res.end ();
}


    var http=require ('http');

    http.createServer (function(req,res) {
        
        data='';
        req.on ('data', chunk => {
            console.log (`Data chunk: ${chunk}`);
            data += chunk;
            sendReq (data,res);

        });


    }).listen (8000);
```

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: 2 requests happening at nearly the same time hsould not be an issue for your application. What is the actual problem with this for you? Try to fix that instead.

Comment: The problem: The response to request 1 is 392 bytes long . The response to request 2 is 28 bytes long. It seems that the response to request 1 is 28 bytes, not 392. The response contents is also wrong.    In case all requests are the same (1 or 2), the response length is right.

Comment: I tried to send each POST to a different port in the Node.js server. Problem was not resolved.

Comment: You should share a better example of your code, because it's missing a lot of stuff!

If you see information from a request 1 in request 2, it probable means that they are sharing the same `data` variable.

Comment: That `data` variable should be defined in the `.on('request')` handler, which I don't see in your source.

Comment: Note that lots of people find it easier to get started with frameworks like Koa and Express. You can totally get it to work with the low-level `http` library, but you can probably find some better examples.

Comment: You are right. I added the missing parts in the code. The external agent can handle only one request at a time.  It gets a TCP request and sends back a TCP reply. But the Node.js can handle multiple requests. So when it gets a TCP reply, it's not clear to what request it belongs.

Comment: Ok, I think I can help with that. I'll add some code with a possible solution.

Comment: Actually sorry I started writing this but it's quite a huge class. You basically need to create a queue system that reads messages from an array, handles them 1 by 1 and then emits responses. The best version of this probably uses asynchronous generators. It's a bit too much work to write it all out, so I hope those keywords help you find a solution. In the Go language you would use a 'channel' for this.

Comment: Hi Evert. Is it possible to change the code so it can handle only one HTTP POST at a time ? What do you mean by "low level http library" ?   Using this library can handle only one POST at a time ?

Comment: No, your code is probably fine. Don't try to solve this on the HTTP layer. instead create a function / class that's responsible for calling your TCP service and puts every request into a queue an handle it one by one.

Comment: I changed the code. No TCP is used. Upon getting code 28, I sent a 392 bytes response. Upon code 11, I sent 28 bytes response. But in the client, the short response is received by the wrong request.

Comment: OK, I'm very confused but still willing to help. Your `sendReq` function is starting to make sense, but how does it get access to the `res` variable? Is there an accurate version of your code you can share?

Comment: Sorry. I fixed the code. Thank you very much.

Comment: The biggest issue I see with your code at a glance, all your variables `len`, `data`, arr`, `num` are not declared. You need to declare them with `const` or `let`. If you don't the variables become global.

Comment: Hi. Major progress ! When I used only local variables, with the no TCP version, problem resolved. Still have the same problem with the version (not currently displayed) that sends TCP request to agent, gets reply and sends the reply back to the client. Thank you very much ! Do you think that for TCP I will have to put every request into a queue ?

Comment: Each request will be pushed to a queue. But who will pull them from the queue ? Should I have a "thread" for this purpose ?

Comment: Yes, because if the request share a TCP connection, that connection is inherently 'global' so you need some kind of mechanism that ensures the messages you're sending over the connection are serialized, and a little queue of promises seems like the right mechanism for this. You can 'pull' from the queue whenever the last message was handled, so at the end of each 'job' you immediately check if there's another one.

Comment: Roughly the steps are: When sending a message add to queue. If queue has 1 item in it, immediately process it or otherwise do nothing. After the currently processed item is done, see if there's other items in the queue and handle those until the queue is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```js
const Net = require('net');
var http=require ('http');
var events=require ('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
var reqQueue =[];
var resQueue =[];

// Create a new TCP client.
const client = new Net.Socket();

/************************************************************************/
/* This callback will be fired upon TCP message sent from server
/************************************************************************/
client.on('data',function(chunk){
    
    //console.log (chunk);
    
    //pull response object from queue
    var res = resQueue.shift ();

    //add response header
    res.writeHead (200,{
        'Content-Type':'text/plain',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'});
    //write response body
    res.write (chunk);
    res.end ();
});

/************************************************************************/
/* Convert number (e.g 0xCAFE2DAD to 4 bytes)
/************************************************************************/
function num2arr(n)
{
    // Mask off 8 bytes at a time then shift them into place
    return [
        (n & 0xFF) >>>  0,
        (n & 0xFF00) >>>  8,
        (n & 0xFF0000) >>> 16,
        (n & 0xFF000000) >>> 24,
    ];
}

/************************************************************************/
/* Connect to TCP server 
/************************************************************************/
function tcpConnect ()
{
    // Send a connection request to the server.
    client.connect({
        host:'localhost',
        port:5100
      });

    client.on('connect',function(){
        console.log('Client: connection established with server');
        
    });
}

/************************************************************************/
/* Convert HTTP request to TCP raw data request
/************************************************************************/
function sendReq (body)
{
    let byteArr=[];

    let len = body.length;
    //get pure data without {,}
    let data = body.substr (1,len-2);
    //console.log (data);
    //convert to array
    let arr = data.split (',');

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        let num = parseInt (arr[i]);
        let numArr = num2arr (num);
        byteArr = byteArr.concat (numArr);
    }

    client.write (Buffer.from(byteArr));
}

/************************************************************************/
/* Event callback fired upon HTTP request 
/************************************************************************/
var eventHandler = function (){
    //console.log ('event fired');
    //console.log (resQueue.length);

    //pull request from queue
    var chunk = reqQueue.shift();
    
    sendReq (chunk);
}

/************************************************************************/
eventEmitter.on ('httpReq', eventHandler);
tcpConnect ();

/************************************************************************/
/*  Launch HTTP server            
/************************************************************************/
http.createServer (function(req,res) {
    
    let data='';
    req.on ('data', chunk => {
        //console.log (`Data chunk: ${chunk}`);
        data += chunk;

        //push response to queue
        resQueue.push (res);

        //push request to queue
        reqQueue.push (data);

        //fire event 
        eventEmitter.emit ('httpReq');
    });
}).listen (8000);
```

This code crashes if the external TCP server is closed.
In this case, the HTTP server should try to reconnect forever.
Is this the right way ?

Evert - Thank you very much !
Zvika